# How to fetch obects from an api call with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to fetch data from an api endpoint using custom hooks and axios in React.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`apiUrl`, {
                console.log(res.data);
            });
            console.log(res.data);

            //not working
            setData(res.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    },[{}]);
```

***res.data*** is returning an object as you can see in the image below.

[image]

When I try to set the data into the local state with the react hook **useEffect** its returning an endless loos when printing out **data**.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the dependency array. `fetchData` is a dependency, so it should be there. To assure `fetchData` has a stable reference, wrap it in `useCallback`, like this:

```js
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`apiUrl`, {
          console.log(res.data);
      });
      console.log(res.data);

      setData(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  },[fetchData]);
```

Comment: THis approach returns an empty object

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you think the empty object in your dependency array is the default return value? Because the dependency array has nothing to do with return value...